# sed, getting an error:sed: unterminated {

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

I'm using below sed command

```
sed -n '\|<tag>|{:n; \|</tag>|!{N;bn}; y|\n| |;p }' test.xml
```

OUTPUT:

```
<tag> <name>jolly</name> <class>2nd</class> <address>  </address> </tag>
<tag> <name>james</name> <class>3rd</class> <address></address> </tag>
<tag> <name>dolly</name> <class>4th</class> <address> <city>delhi</city> </address> </tag>
```

This  command is working fine in bash.But, it is giving below error in /bin/sh(BusyBox sed version:v1.19.0) shell

```
sed: unterminated {
```

How can I fix this error, what is wrong?

Comment: Is this the same `sed` or is it e.g. `gnu sed` vs `busybox sed` ?

Comment: Getting error in busybox sed:BusyBox v1.19.0

Comment: BusyBox is a functionally-reduced composite of several programs.  You will have to experiment with it, building up scripts that happen to work, to stay within its limitations.

Comment: I think you'll have to use it like `...{N;bn;} y... ;p;}` (note the semicolon precedes the brace) or even better `sed -ne '\|<tag>|{:n; \|</tag>|!{N;bn -e '}' -e 'y|\n| |;p' -e '}'`

Comment: I have tried both the ways ...no luck .

Comment: @don_cristi, note that `:n; \|...` is defining the `; \|...` label in POSIX compliant `sed`s (and will be unspecified in the next version of the spec).

Comment: you should use an xml processing tool like `xmlstarlet` instead of sed.  or even something simple like `xml2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) had many extensions far away from [standard sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). One of those is allowing multiple command on the same line in between `{` and `}`. Using any of the extensions is not guaranteed to work in other sed implementations.

[Busybox sed](http://www.busybox.net/BusyBox.html#sed) is a minimal version, so you should stick with standard syntax to make it work:

```
busybox sed -n '/<tag>/ {
  :n
  /<\/tag>/!{
    N
    bn
  }
  y/\n/ /
  p
}' <file
```

Comment: I have tried your  command..but giving `sed: unsupported command |` error

Comment: It worked for me with busybox 1.22.1. Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine if i enter command in multiple lines.is there any way i can use it as single line command. Bcz i want use this command in a shell script.

Comment: I have tried below command (single line) `sed -n '/<tag>/ {; :n;/<\/tag>/!{;N;bn;};y/\n/ /;p;}' test.xml` ..it is working fine.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sai: It seems to be a shell quoting issue instead of `sed`.

Comment: @Sai  You _should_ use a multiple line sed within a shell script.  It's better to do that because multi-line is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Note that it's adding things after `}` or the `b` or `:` commands, or omitting the `;` before the `}`  that is not portable.